# Maven shade output not found

Tags: maven

I'm using the Maven Shade plugin, but I can't find its output.

The log says it clearly : the Maven-shade-plugin has worked.
But in the end, the output of the plugin is not where it is supposed to be.

Why ?

Maven log:

```
--- maven-shade-plugin:2.0:shade (default) @ zploger ---
Including log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17 in the shaded jar.
Including zparkingb:utils:jar:1.5.0 in the shaded jar.
Including zparkingb:swing:jar:1.5.6 in the shaded jar.
(...)
We have a duplicate org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.class in C:\Users\laurent\.m2\repository\xpp3\xpp3_min\1.1.4c\xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
We have a duplicate org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException.class in C:\Users\laurent\.m2\repository\xpp3\xpp3_min\1.1.4c\xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
Replacing D:\work\Zploger\builds\zplogerAudio-exe.jar with D:\work\Zploger\builds\zploger-3.2.0.002-exe.jar
Attaching shaded artifact.
```

And the pom/xml.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>true</keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <shadedClassifierName>exe</shadedClassifierName>
                <finalName>${project.exe_finalname}</finalName>
                <outputDirectory>../builds</outputDirectory>
                <artifactSet>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>demo:*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </artifactSet>                            
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>com.zparkingb.zploger.GUI.Zploger</mainClass>
                    </transformer>                            
                </transformers>                        
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using such an old version of [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) second why are you trying to  change the outputDirectory? and final name etc.

Comment: I didn't remark about the old version. Gonna try it. Other outputDirectory was a test to see if it works better. Other name to have a more convenient name, and also detect the plugin has worked.

Comment: Nothing better with 3.1.1. Still pretending to replace the original .jar by the shaded one, but in practice, nothing happened.

Comment: Have you put the plugin in pluginManagement?

Comment: I made a lot of changes, and now it is working. Don't exactly why. But thanks anyway.